# Is $(0, \infty)$ closed in $\mathbb{R}-0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Our professor asked us: is $(0, \infty)$ closed in $\mathbb{R}-0$?

I feel like there's a problem because $(0, \infty) \in \mathbb{R^2}$

Comment: Here $(0,\infty)$ refers to the interval, that is, the set of all positive numbers -- not to a pair. (The pair would not lie in $\mathbb R^2$ anyway, because $\infty \not \in \mathbb R$.)

Comment: I feel really dumb now, I was just studying algebra a couple hours ago so it got me confused haha...

Comment: You need to answer: is $(0,\infty)$ the intersection of a closed set with $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$?

Comment: Yes but since it's not compact, it's not closed and therefore it's open right?

Comment: Not all closed sets are compact. And not all non-closed sets are open.

Comment: Heine-Borel states that in $\Bbb{R}^n$, closed and bounded is equivalent to compact.  When you delete $\{0\}$, it's not $\Bbb{R}$ any more.  (Oh, and your set is not bounded...)

Comment: In addition to T. Eskin's comment, "not closed" doesn't imply "open". Example: $\mathbb{R}$ is closed and open in itself, but not compact.

Answer (score 1):

This question only makes sense when you specify a topology (a way to identify open sets, whose complements are the closed sets).  The usual topology when one starts with a topological space, say $\Bbb{R}$, and modifies it by deleting parts or only keeping parts is the subspace topology.  In the subspace topology, a set is closed if it is what remains of a closed set in the original space after parts are deleted/kept.  For instance, the interval $(-1,2)$ is open in $\Bbb{R}$ (with the usual topology) and is still *open* in $[0,1] \subset \Bbb{R}$ in the subspace topology because what is left of it after keeping only $[0,1]$ is $[0,1]$, so $[0,1]$ is "open in the subspace topology".

Given that, can you tell whether $[0,\infty)$ is closed in $\Bbb{R}$ and would therefore remain closed in $\Bbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ in the subspace topology?

> It is closed in $\Bbb{R}$ because it only has one endpoint and that endpoint is included.  (This uses standard facts about the usual topology on $\Bbb{R}$.  In a different space or with $\Bbb{R}$ and a strange topology, that claim may not work.)  Consequently, $(0,\infty)$ is a closed set in the subspace topology.  It is *also* an open set because $(0,\infty)$ is one in $\Bbb{R}$ and its restriction to the subspace is itself.

So yeah.  Intervals can be simultaneously open and closed in the subspace topology.

Answer (score 0):

The union of intervals $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)=\mathbb{R}-0$, yes? So $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ is both closed and open in this situation.

The definition of closed often used is that a closed set contains all its limit points. $0$ is not a limit point in this space, so the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ doesn't converge for example.

Pick any sequnce $x_n\in(0,\infty)$ that is convergent. It must converge to a positive number $x$. Hence we can find an open set containing $x$ that is a subset of $(0,\infty)$ which contains all other further members of the sequence. Therefor all limit points are contained in $(0,\infty)$ and it is closed.